# Gimp python-fu: How to crop layer to selection

Tags: gimp, python-fu

What is the GIMP API call to crop a layer to a selection, equivalent to *Layer -> Crop to Selection* in the GUI?

I looked in the Procedure Browser but the calls I found (`gimp-crop` and `gimp-image-crop`) perform the crop on the image, not a layer.

(What I really want to do is cut-and-paste multiple layers at once; I'm making a plug-in to help.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use `pdb.gimp_layer_resize()` using the data from `pdb.gimp_selection_bounds(image)`.

```
x0,y0 = pdb.gimp_drawable_offsets(layer)
non_empty, x1, y1, x2, y2 = pdb.gimp_selection_bounds(image)
pdb.gimp_layer_resize(layer,x2-x1,y2-y1,x0-x1,y0-y1)
```